# Method not allowed - redirect using incorrect method

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I have been working on a simple Laravel Inertia Vue3 application. It has one resource route.

```
Route::resource('contact', \App\Http\Controllers\ContactController::class);
```

This provides the named routes contact.index .store .create .show .update .destroy and .edit

Nice and simple so far.

I have a useForm form variable in my Vue component with some assigned variables

```
let form = useForm({ ... });
```

I have a submit method in the same component

```
let submit = () => {
    if(props.edit) {
        form.patch(`/contact/${props.contact.id}`);
    } else {
        form.post(`/contact`);
    }
}
```

Again nothing complex. The post method fires off correctly and redirects

```
    Contact::query()->create($request->all());

    return redirect()->to(route('contact.index'));
```

For full disclosure of the update method, please see below:

```
public function update(Request $request, Contact $contact): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
{
    $contact->fill($request->all())->save();

    return redirect()->to(route('contact.show', ['contact' => $contact]));
}
```

This works in the same way as store. Simple and then redirects... but it doesn't.

What happens is that it runs the patch and then calls redirect
The redirect carries the patch method through ending up with a 405 if I use the index route (declared as get). If I use `back()` I get the same thing. If I use the show route, it redirects in a loop because the patch route uses the same URL /contact/{contact}

I have built Laravel applications for the last 5 years and have not had an issue like this before when using a named route. Have I missed something basic? If not its possibly a configuration issue although I am not sure what.

I am running Laravel 9.19 with webpack manually installed as its been changed to Vite on the current release. I have no Vue errors or warnings and no Laravel logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This time I really am answering my own question.

I was a total idiot and missed a step when setting up inertia js. I was attempting to retrieve errors with the useform method and what happened was I received nothing.

So I though I would double check the docs.

Turns out I missed adding this middleware to the web middleware group in the kernel!

```
\App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
```

I can now use the .patch method I had before and no need for any additional code

Answer (score 1):

there is a difference between PUT and PATCH requests on laravel-level.
Please run php artisan route:list - and see which one is used in your case, There is a big chance that you using PUT, not patch :)

Comment: I missed the .put method in the useform spec. I will give it a go. I will also recheck the route list and see what it marks the update route as

Comment: `PUT|PATCH       contact/{contact} ........................................................................................................................................................ contact.update › ContactController@update`

Comment: So the trick here was not about using .put or .patch. I remembered laravel has this weird javascript issue sometimes with patches and puts and recommends sending certain types of data as a post with a patch method field. I'll post it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

So good ol' Laravel got me again.

Alexander Dyriavin got me on the right course with his answer about put and patch, however, it wasn't really the solution.

The solution:

```
    form.transform((data) => ({
        ...data,
        _method: 'PUT' //spoof added to request
    })).post(`/contact/${props.contact.id}`); //sent as a post instead
```

The Laravel docs allow you to spoof methods https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#method-spoofing by posting them with a `_method` field.

Simply put, a patch or put request would have always failed with a redirect from Laravel. In the past I would have used them with Axios and handled a JSON response directly.